# Laravel5 RouteServiceProvider not working

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

could you help me with my problem? I'm working with laravel5 `App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider`. I'm trying to add to routes prefix in dependence on current lang. E.g.:
I have routes.php, where are routes like:

```
/blog
/home
```

And I need to do this:
I url is for example:

```
/en/blog
```

I get the "lang" from url and I want to add routes prefix, to match it with my routes. So It will do smth. like this:

```
$router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'prefix' => $locale], function($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
});
```

I don't know why, but it doesn't work... if url is `/en/blog`, It didn't match with any route, anyway it should... 
I also tried to change namespace and in some controller method do this:

```
die(print_r(Route::getCurrentRoute()));
```

but namespace for all routes was: `App\Controllers`

Do you have an idea, why it doesn't work?

In my opinion, RouteServiceProvider isn't loaded, because also, when I try to put in method `map` or method `boot` `die('smth');` it didn't do anything...

Here is my route service provider:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router, Request $request)
    {
        $locale = $request->segment(1);
        $this->app->setLocale($locale);

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'prefix' => $locale], function($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I see no one has responded to your question, I don't know if you have marked this as resolved but based on what I could tell:

- To replicate your problem I ran `php artisan route:cache`

This means that Laravel is looking at the stored cache for the routes and not the routes.php or route service provider file you changed.

That means when I change the map function in `RouteServiceProvider.php` nothing will happen

```
public function map(Router $router, Request $request)
{
    /*
    $locale = $request->segment(1);
    $this->app->setLocale($locale);

    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'prefix' => $locale], function($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
    */

}
```

You may already have already solved your problem by restarting your server however, a specific vendor file might be caching your routes for you.

- So in order to clear your cache simply run `php artisan route:clear`

Afterwards all changes to your `RouteServiceProvider.php` file should be immediate. So you can visit `/en` but in order to force the prefix you need to add in a language middleware.

Searching around I think you were working off of [the laracast blogs multiple locales post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website)

- So you still need to create a middleware using `php artisan make:middleware Language` and change its handle() function

After that just add in the Language middleware to `Kernel.php` in order to force Laravel to route you to `/en`

```
protected $middleware = [
    'App\Http\Middleware\Language'
];
```

Hope that solves your problem, better late than never